# Apple Watch mute only notifications and not alarms

Tags: notifications, apple-watch, watchos, do-not-disturb

Is there a way to mimic the `Do not Disturb` mode found in the iPhone on my Apple Watch?

I'd like to **receive** notifications but without any sound nor haptic feedback. I know I can use the `Silence` mode, but that silences my alarms and notifications too!

So, once again I'd like to mute *only* the notifications (not alarms) but still receive them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try enabling Do not disturb on the Apple Watch, and turn off "Mirror iPhone" under the Do Not Disturb section of the Apple Watch App, General > Do not disturb > Mirror iPhone. This was you keep DND separate from the phone as I assume you still want notifications on your phone to alert you.